# What if my question is not answered nether commented and I do not have enough reputation to start a bounty?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties, unanswered-questions

Suppose I asked some question, that got enough (28-30) views to get an answer or at least a comment. But neither a comment nor any answer is posted. 
So I should start a bounty so that it gets people's attention but the thing is I do not have enough reputations to start a bounty.

So what should I do in that case? Should I keep editing my question to bump it or what?

Comment: maybe you can contact moderator.

Comment: Not what mod contacts are for.  Those sorts of flags are a waste of moderator time.

Comment: @Journeyman Geek How many moderators are there btw ?

Comment: LOL Doda, you're really making me laugh, idk why.

Comment: 440+ is definitely enough for a bountu of `50`

Comment: @Siraj If you don't know why you are laughing then you need to consult a doctor :D

Comment: Depends on the site - but at least 3. *But* "I don't have an answer" is not a good use of flags. Any user can post an answer, and there's a lot of users who probably have better general or specific knowledge in a field on the site I moderate on. There's *25* on SO but they probably work harder than anyone else, so its not numbers, its proper use of flags.

Comment: Well, I am not asked this question specifically for the question you just commented on. I asked generally, what if someone do not have?

Comment: @Siraj as IDebug said 445 is more than enough for a bounty.

Comment: Doda, I said this is not specifically about my question what I asked on StackOverflow. This is a general question in such case

Answer (score 5):

Don't edit to bump. Edit to *improve*. Flesh out your question - add what you've worked out so far. By adding what hasn't worked, and what has partially worked, you kind of help get closer to a solution.

Its worth considering as well, sometimes questions just are really really hard, and the right person might not have come across it yet. Waiting is also often an option.

I actually had the same issue with a [specific question](https://superuser.com/questions/342107/getting-macro-keys-from-a-razer-blackwidow-to-work-on-linux) on Super User. I went through multiple improvements, more than one bounty, and eventually got an answer that worked (though, razer changed their API/firmware later so the selected answer *might* not work on all keyboards).

The best way to get an answer is to also spend the time to work it through, document, and help others help push you past the line.

Comment: I have given every detail in the question and by drawing pictures for the clarification in my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/47326268/5132337
I'm still making changes in question to make it better.

Answer (score 0):

The rule of thumb is that **editing should make your question *clearer***, or **improve it**.

In general, if you can't offer a bounty for whatever reason, just edit it. The most common case is that people are unclear of what you're asking, and it also common that they do not think the question is bad enough for a downvote, so they choose to ignore it.